# heart beat heartbeat and heart beating

Tags: difference

Is there any difference (or wrong) among the following:

1. It's heart beat has stopped.
2. It's heartbeat has stopped.
3. It's heart beating has stopped.
4. It's heart has stopped beating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need **its**, not **it's**! (**Its** is the possessive pronoun. **It's** means "it is".)

> 2. Its heartbeat has stopped.

is both perfect and colloquial.

> 4. Its heart has stopped beating.

is perfect English, but perhaps a little less colloquial.

The other two are wrong.

Comment: Nice and clear, thank you!